# Tracking user clicks and angle in YouTube/360 player

Tags: javascript, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

We are preparing an youtube activation within one year and we are considering using the standard YouTube player if possible - if not, we will try with custom embed for now, but maybe someone knows about possible YT updates? I have a few questions:

- can I track what player area have user clicked and store the data in
  YouTube/Analytics?
- is it possible to check which area and what direction was user looking at in 360 when he/she clicked?
- can I identify the user somehow?

Thanks in advance

Jakub

Comment: Did you get any solution to this ?